# Why target-signer account balance is deducted in parity-bridges-common?

Tags: parity-bridges-common

Hi I'm sending a message from millau-rialto in the bridge in which giving recipient and amount in the command. But the problem the source signer is only giving transaction fee and the target signer on another chain is paying the amount. Can someone please help me through this

```
./target/debug/substrate-relay send-message millau-to-rialto \
            --source-host localhost \
            --source-port $MILLAU_PORT \
            --source-signer //Alice\
            --target-signer //Eve \
            --lane 00000000 \
            --origin Target \
            transfer \
            --amount 10000000000000 \
            --recipient 5qTnmq6AGPoZVr29wDsgXhoLhpp3sCukSFXh7zGSaQtgCa1U \
```